# Jest hangs on Supertest's POST and does not execute "posttest" script

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I'm having issues with Jest with Express and Supertest with only one test to create an user. If the database is clean it works but the console displays the following:

[image]

which makes `posttest`, what undoes all the migrations, not to be executed.

The full warning message is:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
>
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

I've attempted to use `done()`, but the not only the problem of hanging persists, it doesn't show what's the problem, like without `done()`. Even a simple sum assertion will make Jest hang.

I don't have much to show, it is a simple test yet so many trouble. Maybe if you need more info, [this is the repository](https://github.com/mfgabriel92/bootcamp-gostack-7-desafio03).

Comment: Are you still including `password_hash` in the `send` object, as in https://github.com/mfgabriel92/bootcamp-gostack-7-desafio03/blob/master/__tests__/functional/user.test.js ?

Comment: No, it is `password` now. The test, when the database is clean, is successful, but something prevents Jest from exiting and `posttest` does not run.

Comment: Even a simple sum assertion will cause Jest to hang. @mccallofthewild

Comment: Is it hanging permanently, or is Jest just timing out? If it's the latter, try adding `jest.setTimeout(60000)` at the top

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal working example:

`app.js`:

```js
import express, { Router } from 'express';

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.server = express();

    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
    this.exceptions();
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.server.use(express.json());
  }

  routes() {
    const routes = new Router();
    routes.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
      res.status(201).json({ user: {} });
    });
    this.server.use(routes);
  }

  exceptions() {
    this.server.use(async (err, req, res, next) => {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    });
  }
}

export default new App().server;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
import app from './app';
import request from 'supertest';

describe('User', () => {
  it('Should create a new user', async () => {
    const response = await request(app)
      .post('/api/users')
      .send({
        first_name: 'Lorem',
        last_name: 'Ipsum',
        email: 'lorem@ipsum.com',
        password: '12345678',
      });

    expect(response.status).toBe(201);
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('user');
  });
});
```

Functional test result with coverage report:

```sh
☁  jest-codelab [master] ⚡  npx jest --coverage --verbose /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/57897576/app.test.js
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57897576/app.test.js
  User
    ✓ Should create a new user (40ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |       90 |      100 |       75 |    94.44 |                   |
 app.js   |       90 |      100 |       75 |    94.44 |                26 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.617s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57897576